# Google analytic is showing Package Name

Tags: android, google-analytics

Recently I have upgraded GAv4 from GAv3 , But there are some activities where I did not applied GA code but that package names are showing on DashBoard But where I have used these code showing screen name.

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((AnalyticsSampleApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(
    TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name.`enter code here`

t.setScreenName(screenName);

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

for Java and

```
    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
    <screenName name="com.mypackage">Screen Name
</screenName>
```

in xml.

plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are setting screen name as your package name that's why its showing package name..use
 `<string name="ga_appName">AppName</string>` 
and set screen name from code somthing like that 
`t.setScreenName("MainActivity");`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use AppName then it will show appName on dashboard, But I don't want to show anything for that activities, where I did not applied GA code.